# Instantiate a class in a module

Tags: python

I come from a ruby background and I am noticing some differences to python... In ruby, when I need to create a helper I usually go for a module, something like the below:

```
module QueryHelper
  def db_client
    @db ||= DBClient.new
  end

  def query
    db_client.select('whateverquery')
  end
end
```

In python tho, I do something like the following:

```
db_client = DBClient()

def query():
    return db_client.select('whateverquery')
```

My only worry with the above is that every time I call query() function it will try to instantiate DBClient() over and over... but based on reading and testing, that does not seem to occur due to some caching mechanism in python when I import a module...

The question is if the above in python is bad practice, if so, why and how can it be improved? perhaps lazy evaluating it? Or if you guys believe it's ok as is...

Comment: `db_client` is an instance of `DBClient`, so any calls using `db_client.` are using that same instance (so long as that name is not pointed anywhere else).  To contrast however, if you were to use `DBClient().select('whatever')`, then a new instance would be created (and quickly garbage collected) on every call to `query()`.

Answer (score 3):

No. The `query` function will not be re-instantiated every time you call it. This is because you've already created an instance of `DBClient` *outside* of the `query` function. This means that your current code is fine as is.

If your intention was to create a new instance of `DBClient` every time `query` is called, then you should just move the declaration into the `query` function, like this:

```
def query():
    db_client = DBClient()
    return db_client.select( ... )
```

Answer (score -1):

In short you would like to add a method to the DBClient object? Why not adding it dynamically?

```
# defining the method to add 
def query(self, command):
    return self.select(command)

# Actually adding it to the DBClient class
DBClient.query = query

# Instances now come with the newly added method
db_client = DBClient()

# Using the method 
return_command_1 = db_client.query("my_command_1")
return_command_2 = db_client.query("my_command_2")
```

Credits to [Igor Sobreira](http://igorsobreira.com/2011/02/06/adding-methods-dynamically-in-python.html).

Comment: Actually I am looking to use a method within DBClient... just looking to know whether the way I use my module and instantiate my class within my module is acceptable... apparently it is...

Comment: oh, then you just need to do it like this:
`db_client = DBClient()
return_command_1 = db_client.query("my_command_1")
return_command_2 = db_client.query("my_command_2")`